# Not able to pass a variable entirely as a SQL statement in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter to run my queries. I have this object of attribute having this value: `SELECT description FROM sys_forms_master ORDER BY description`. This query is stored in `$test->lov_sql` and works perfectly.

I am running this line of code to run my queries in CodeIgniter : `$query = $this->db->query($test->lov_sql)`. But this gives me the error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mysqli::query(): Empty query

Comment: Maybe it filters out keywords like sys and master automatically?

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond But when I run my query as a string, that is, $query = $this->db->query("SELECT description FROM sys_forms_master ORDER BY description"), it works perfectly and gives me no such error.

Comment: try executing `var_dump($test); die();` before your call to the query.  Maybe the var isn't being set properly?

Comment: Maybe you should use `$this->test->lov_sql`?

Comment: You say, "stored in $test->lov_sql and works perfectly." and then you say "But this gives me the error:" So which statement is correct. Can you make yourself more clear please. The error is saying that `$test->lov_sql` is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this syntax to send a SQL query with Codeigniter:

```
$sql="SELECT description FROM sys_forms_master ORDER BY description"
```

and then execute and return the query:

```
$query= $this->db   ->query($sql);  
return $query->result();
```

this is all done in your model. see also [Codeigniter's MVC](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html#model-view-controller):